# Linq results different than the sql result

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am having an MVC4 web application where I am using LINQ.

I have the below query which results 53 rows in SQL.

```sql
    select * from table1 t join
    [table2] tpf on t.TestID=tpf.TestID
    join
     table3 pf on tpf.Test2ID =pf.Test2ID
    join table4 pfp on
    pf.Test3ID = pfp.Test3ID
     join table5 p on pfp.Test5ID = p.Test5ID  where t.testtypeid=1
     order by pfp.Test3ID,pf.Test2ID
```

If I convert the same query as below it returns more records.

```cs
 trvm.MyTestVMs = (
    from tt in db.table1s
    join ttpf in db.table2s on tt.TestID equals ttpf.TestID                      
    join pf in db.table3s on ttpf.Test2ID equals pf.Test2ID

    join pfp in db.table4s on pf.Test3ID equals pfp.Test3ID
    join p in table5s on pfp.Test5ID equals p.Test5ID
    where tt.testtypeid == 1

    orderby pfp.Test3ID
    orderby pf.Test2ID 

    select new MyTestVM
    {
        FamilyID = pf.Test2ID,
        ProductID = p.Test3ID,
        Desc = p.Description
    }
).ToList();
```

The result which is getting from SQL and the above LINQ varies. Actually, there are some duplicate result I am getting from the LINQ query. What is causing this difference?

Comment: Are database views involved or just tables? Tables w/o PK?

Comment: just tables. primary key is there in the tables

Comment: Fix your `order by` clause, then change the code like this `var query = ( ...);` (without `ToList()` call), then `var sql = query.ToString(); trvm.ProductFamilyProductVMs = query.ToList();`, put a breakpoint and see it `sql` variable contains a SQL query text. If yes, open it with the Text Visualizer, copy and paste it in the question.

Comment: Updated question with sql

Comment: The generated SQL contains some redundant (duplicate) joins, not sure if that's the problem, could you try executing it inside the database (replace `@p__linq...` with constants) and see if it returns correct number of rows or not.

Comment: It gives wrong out put. I have ran a sql trace and same is updated in the question. Any idea why therte is duplicate joins in linq. and how i can correct it

Comment: Unfortunately I have no EF4 environment, all my experience is with the latest EF6. But once you know the problem, may be someone else can help you, good luck.

Comment: i am also usign EF version 6.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103748/discussion-between-jubi-and-ivan-stoev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the LINQ query is not equivalent to the SQL query posted due to the usage of a `products` query variable (not shown in the post) which causes one of the `many-to-many` link table to be included twice, thus producing more records.

One way to fix the problem is to replace `products` with `db.Products` and apply the same filters as in the query variables you were trying to reuse.

But if you want to reuse query variables, then here is the correct way to do that:

```
// Eliminate the need of DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dt) inside the queries
dt = dt.Date;

// Queries

var productFamilys = (
     from tt in db.TestTypes
     join ttpf in db.TestTypeProductFamilys on tt.TestTypeID equals ttpf.TestTypeID
     join pf in db.ProductFamilys on ttpf.ProductFamilyID equals pf.ProductFamilyID
     where tt.TestTypeID == TestTypeID
     where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(pf.StartDate) <= dt
     where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(pf.EndDate) > dt
     select pf
 );

var productFamilyProducts = (
    from pf in productFamilys
    join pfp in db.ProductFamilyProducts on pf.ProductFamilyID equals pfp.ProductFamilyID
    join p in db.Products on pfp.ProductID equals p.ProductID
    where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.StartDate) <= dt
    where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.EndDate) > dt
    select new { Family = pf, Product = p }
);

var products = (
    from pfp in productFamilyProducts
    select pfp.Product
);

var productFamilyProductVMs = (
    from pfp in productFamilyProducts
    orderby pfp.Product.ProductID, pfp.Family.ProductFamilyID
    select new ProductFamilyProductVM
    {
        ProductFamilyID = pfp.Family.ProductFamilyID,
        ProductID = pfp.Product.ProductID,
        ProdDesc = pfp.Product.Description
    }
);

// Results
trvm.ProductFamilys = productFamilys.ToList(); 
trvm.Products = products.ToList(); 
trvm.ProductFamilyProductVMs = productFamilyProductVMs.ToList();
```

Now the SQL for the last query (the one in question) looks like this

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[ProductFamilyID] AS [ProductFamilyID], 
    [Project1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Project1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent2].[ProductFamilyID] AS [ProductFamilyID], 
        [Extent4].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
        [Extent4].[Description] AS [Description]
        FROM    [dbo].[TestTypeProductFamilies] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductFamilies] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProductFamilyID] = [Extent2].[ProductFamilyID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductFamilyProducts] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ProductFamilyID] = [Extent3].[ProductFamilyID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ProductID] = [Extent4].[ProductID]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[TestTypeID] = @p__linq__0) AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent2].[StartDate], 102) ,  102)) <= @p__linq__1) AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent2].[EndDate], 102) ,  102)) > @p__linq__2) AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent4].[StartDate], 102) ,  102)) <= @p__linq__3) AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent4].[EndDate], 102) ,  102)) > @p__linq__4)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[ProductID] ASC, [Project1].[ProductFamilyID] ASC
```

i.e. pretty similar to the sample SQL query and should produce the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Result is different because in your second query , you have two  "OrderBy" and because of that, the second OrderBy it's works over the collection which is result of first "OrderBy" and is reordering the items.
Change

```
     orderby pfp.ProductID
     orderby pf.ProductFamilyID
```

from your second query in

```
orderby pfp.ProductID, pf.ProductFamilyID
```

to get same results

Comment: In both the queries the orderby is same orderby pfp.ProductID, pf.ProductFamilyID

Comment: In my first query order by is order by pfp.ProductID,pf.ProductFamilyID and in second orderby pfp.ProductID
                    orderby pf.ProductFamilyID. What changes i need to make here

Comment: i will try. But i wonder the order by is just ordering the output. How is it going to get more number of records.

Comment: @jubi, ,let's try this again.  I'm asking three questions and getting answers to one of them... On the rows returned by Linq, are there ANY rows you don't WANT returned or are they ALL correct but duplicates of the original 53?  How many are you getting?  Please try to address each question as they will help us help you.

Comment: 1) They are correct but duplicates of origina; 2) sql returns 53 which is correct and linq returns 73 which has duplicate records. sorry for the confusion. I have updted the question with the trace from sqql server. Hope it gives a light to the actual problem